# Redirection to a URL with hyphen doesn't work in Spring Gateway application

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, spring-cloud-gateway

```
routeBuilder.route(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(), r ->
                r.path(path)
                        .filters(f -> f.redirect(301,'https://hlt.com/ask-wisely'))
                        .uri("no://op"));
```

The routebuilder with a redirection to a url containing hyphen(https://hlt.com/ask-wisely) doesn't work. If I remove the hyphen, it works well. Anything to make it work ?